# Insert multiple records in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,"ok1"),(2,"ok2");

As i understood ,Multiple rows insertion not allowed in Oracle Database.

Please confirm me if any other alternatives for inserting multiple records into oracle DB with above format.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle only allows one row to be inserted at a time.  So use two `inserts`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME)
    VALUES (1, 'ok1');

INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME)
    VALUES (2, 'ok2');
```

Or use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME)
    SELECT 1 'ok1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'ok2' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks . Yes - the above option is working . i have already tested . But looking for if any other  option.

Comment: If you need load a lot of records from a flat file, sql loader is a good option. External tables  is another option

Comment: One disadvantage with this is we cant use a sequnce.nextval as it is prohibited in union of select